# Pyspark error : reading a tsv.gz dataframe reads 0 rows each time even though there are rows in source

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I have the following code;

```
test_df = (spark.read
         .schema(newSchema)
         .option("header", "true")
         .option("delimiter", "\t").csv("wasbs://container@AzureStorageAcc.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2021/02/05/"))
```

But this does not seem to work. Is there any other way to read tsv.gz as a spark dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `.format("cloudFiles")` from your command, this is only for working with [structured streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader), and I suspect that it may interfere with `.csv`.

Comment: I tried doing that, still didn't work, same error